# How do I find all other IP addresses on my domain using sockets

Tags: android, ios, sockets

Is there a way to find/discover any other devices on my wireles network domain using sockets?  I am trying to write an interoperable wifi p2p connection between iOS and Android.  I believe I can establish a 2-way client/server wifi infrastructure connection between the 2 mobile phones using sockets.  In this case I have a wifi router as the domain access point.  My issue is how can I get the IP address of other devices on my wifi domain.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically done by broadcasting to your subnet (via UDP) and letting other listening devices discover your broadcast.

You may find that other devices are already broadcasting.

Apple has the [Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/) library, which may help you discover devices.

Another alternative is [GameKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkmatch).

Comment: Learn something new every day.  Did not know this feature existed.  I just check it out and found that by sending a UDP packet to 255.255.255.255, I can find every device on my local network.  Bonjour is on my list to check out.  However, using Javascript and sockets.io would be better for my implementation.

Comment: Learn something new everyday.  Just checked it out and found that sending a UDP packet to 255.255.255.255 gives me all devices on my local network.  Pretty cool.  Bonjour is on my list.  However, javascript with sockets.io would be better for my application.

Comment: Broadcasting to 255.255.255.255 is *supposed* to broadcast to all subnets of the local network, but in reality it is usually blocked from crossing subnet boundaries, or just plain blocked at all. It is usually best to broadcast only to your device's local subnet using its actual broadcast IP. For example, if your devices are connected to a WiFi network as 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2, with both using a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0, then the broadcast IP for their subnet is 192.168.0.255.